# Associated model auto-update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have a problem with model automatic updates, can anybody suggest why?

**City** is model for cities, used across application. **Customer** is model that use city, but not necessary. I've tried different `has_one`, `belongs_to` combinations, FYI.

```
rails g model city title:string customer:references
rails g model customer title:string city:references

class City < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :customer, optional: true, autosave: true
end
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :city, autosave: true
end
```

Tried `belongs_to :city`, same effect.

Now we try to seed db with debug data:

```
City.create({title:'City 1'})
city_1 = City.find_by( id: 1 )
Customer.create(title:'Customer 1', city: city_1)
```

And after `db:reset` we have database, table `'cities'` with `'City 1'` record, but column `customer_id` is empty. It should contain id of 'customer 1' I believe. For example, to be able to call `Customer.all.includes(:city)`.

Comment: Can you add both the migrations to question, Not sure how migrations generated via 
`rails g model city title:string customer:references` and `rails g model customer title:string city:references` will work if there is foreign_key constrains present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

City is model for cities, used across application

```
rails g model city title:string
```

city.rb

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  #has_many :customers
end
```

Customer is model that use city, but not necessary.

```
rails g model customer title:string city:references
```

customer.rb(add `optional: true` to achieve `but not necessary.`)

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :city, optional: true 
end
```

Queries= >

```
city = City.create({title:'City 1'})
city_1 = City.find_by( id: 1 )
Customer.create(title:'Customer 1', city: city_1)
#Customer.create(title:'Customer 1', city_id: city_1.id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, seems it works. Just can't understand why. "belongs_to" seems right for Customer, but why has_one/has_many work in different manner in that case?

Comment: @cepera63 Though i'm not good in explanation, in general every customer should exist with a city, so called city can exists without customer. that's what i have explained in answer. hopefully that make sense. anyway feel free to accept answer if it helped you. :) let me know for further guidance as well.